# Ubuntu Snappy for Raspberry Pi 2 with capacitive touch display

Tags: touchscreen, ubuntu-core, raspberrypi

Any idea whether the original Raspberry Pi 7" capacitive touch screen (https://www.raspberrypi.org/products/raspberry-pi-touch-display) is supported in the Raspberry Pi (v2) version of Ubuntu Snappy?

Comment: Oh, now it is clear. Currently Ubuntu Snappy, at least for Raspberry Pi v2, has no support for graphics at all. Furthermore, it doesn't recognize the connected LCD display and only outputs to HDMI (with weird random artifacts on the screen) and has extremely limited repository. Did I mention complete lack of documentation? I did now. I'm rather disappointed.

Comment: Snappy isn't really for average users to play with. It's a platform mostly for developers, and is in very early stages. Overtime this project will grow. No need to be disappointed - like i said it is not for average users

Comment: Well, @Serg, I use TinyCore (actually the PiCore) in a serious project, and it does work fantastically. I heard of Snappy, and since my previous project included Ubuntu on a sort of embedded system, I thought that it may do the job for RasPi2, including running from RAM, GUI on a TFT display, and runnng a Java app, but apparently Snappy is (currently?) more like a base for headless devices. Back to TinyCore!